# How to genetrate input field and their value based on user input on the other input field in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an input field where user will enter isbn number based on the input number i need to populate two input field i.e book title and book author name i am calling a javscript function on onblur of input and i am getting the correct value but my problem is that if user will not move their cursor from the input field and click on submit button then how i will populate these two input field in these scenario onblur is not working

```
<form name="post" id="post" method="post" action="#">
   <input type="text" name="price" id="price">
   <input type="text" name="isbn_number" id="isbn_number" onblur="getdetail()">
</form>
```

Comment: Use onchange instead of onblur? And check if all fields are valid before allowing the user to submit.

Comment: Does onchange not work?

Comment: @Shilly But when user are submitting the form at time these two fields has not created then how i can put validation for those field in client side

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue, / what you want from us, is your AJAX code not working or?

Comment: By having an onclick event handler on the submit button that will cancel the submit if thigns aren't valid. Or only make the submit button clickable once everything is valid. Or have the server return an error stating that the two fields aren't inputted. Or by putting the 'required' attribute on all fields that are required. (if your browser supports it) So there's many options.

Comment: @Shilly when my user clicking on submit button without moving their cursor from the input field at that time my input field has not been generated then how can put the validation for these two filed the filed will only generate if my function will call before submitting the form so i want if user will click on the submit button without moving cursor from input field in this scenario my form should not submitted instead two input filed should be populated

Comment: if you use onchange function then getdetail() function will be called when user click on submit, you can use onfocus function so cursor will be in your price field, then if user click on submit validation function will be called.

Comment: @RajaUsmanMehmood i want to call getdetail() function if it has not been called before on this page so that i can generate the two input field and i can show to the user they need to enter the value in this two field

Answer (score 0):

Pick your preferred solution and adapt it to your website:

1) If your browser supports it, the easiest is make all your fields required and use onchange instead of onblur. This will force the user to enter an isbn, which will trigger the onchange containing more inputs with required.

```
<form name="post" id="post" method="post" action="#">
   <input type="text" name="price" id="price" required>
   <input type="text" name="isbn_number" id="isbn_number" onchange="getdetail()" required>
</form>
```

2) Do manual submitting after checking fields.

```
<form name="post" id="post" method="post" action="#">
   <input type="text" name="price" id="price">
   <input type="text" name="isbn_number" id="isbn_number" onblur="getdetail()">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
<script>
    document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]').addEventListener('click', function ( event ) {
        var valid = false;
        event.preventDefault();
        // ...
        // add validation code here.
        // ...
        if (valid) document.querySelector('#post').submit();
    });
</script>
```

3) Only activate the submit if everything is valid.

```
<form name="post" id="post" method="post" action="#">
   <input type="text" name="price" id="price">
   <input type="text" name="isbn_number" id="isbn_number">
   <input type="submit" disabled="disabled">
</form>
<script>
    var valid = false;
    document.querySelector('#post').addEventListener('change', function ( event ) {
        if (event.target.name === 'isbn_number') getdetail();
        // ...
        // add validation code
        // if (stuff && stuff && stuff) valid = true;
        if (valid) document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]').removeAttribute('disabled');
    });
</script>
```